# How to get an object by its uid?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, reflection

Is there any way to get an object by it's UID so that the following code would work?

When the function finishes, the value of property "xxx" should be "string two" not "string one".

```
// Test class
public function test():void {
    this.xxx = "string one";
    foo.bar(this.xxx);
    trace(this.xxx); // Prints: string two
}

// Foo class
public function bar(value:*):void {
    // ... What would I have to do here to get the property, not its value?
    value = "string two";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the Box brackets? I know this is not the OO way of doing the thing but Action script supports it and it looks like a good alternative here.

```
class Test {
public var xxx:String;

public function test():void {
    this.xxx = "string one";
    foo.bar(this,"xxx"); // actual name of property as string ;litral
    trace(this.xxx); // Prints: string two
  }
}

class Foo {
public function bar(test:*,prop:String):void {
    //test could be from any class . 
    test[prop] = "string two";
  }
}
```

This should do the trick. But You need to make sure whichever code calls "bar" method passes a valid object which has "xxx" property defined as this code is not type safe any more.

Comment: That looks good I guess, well it can benefit from CTRL+Space.

Answer (score 0):

A function's parameter (a reference to a variable) can't be changed. It's not a pointer. You can assign other variables to it, but it won't change the argument passed to that function. But you can change the argument's properties:

```
class Test {
    public var xxx:String;

    public function test():void {
        this.xxx = "string one";
        foo.bar(this);
        trace(this.xxx); // Prints: string two
    }
}


class Foo {
    public function bar(test:Test):void {
        test.xxx = "string two";
    }
}
```

Of course for this to work, the class `Foo` has to know `Test` and also which property to change. This makes everything less dynamic and is maybe not what you want. It's a case where you could use an `Interface`. Or you might want to stick to common patterns like using a getter and assigning the value to the appropriate property:

```
class Test {
    public var xxx:String;

    public function test():void {
        this.xxx = "string one";
        this.xxx = foo.getValue();
        trace(this.xxx); // Prints: string two
    }
}


class Foo {
    public function getValue():String{
        return "string two";
    }
}
```

Comment: But couldn't I send the UID of the pointer to the function and form it get the actual pointer? In my case there is no way to use interfaces, also the value assignment has to be done from within the second function.

Answer (score 0):

To get to a property, the easiest way is to encapsulate the property into an object, pass it to the function, and then retrieve it:

```
// Test class
public function test():void {
    var obj: Object = new Object();
    obj.variable = "string one";
    foo.bar(obj);
    trace(obj.variable); // Prints: string two
}

// Foo class
public function bar(value:Object):void {
    value.variable = "string two";
}
```

But why would you want to do this? It's much better in every way to just do `xxx = foo.bar();`

Comment: I can't do that, It's part of a small framework I'm writing to encapsulate RemoteObjects. So "the right way" wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

*Pass-by-value*:

When passing a variable into a function the variable is copied. Any changes you make to the variable aren't reflected back once you exit.

*Pass-by-reference*:

When passing a variable into a function, the "pointer" to the variable is passed. Any changes you make to the variable are copied over.

In AS3, everything is pass-by-reference, *except* primitives (Boolean, String, int, uint, etc), which have special operators behind the scenes to make them act like pass-by-value. As `xxx` is a String, this is what's happening. (Also, Strings are immutable; you can't actually change their value).

How to fix it (as others have said):

- Pass the `Test` object itself to the `bar()` function: `bar( this );`
- Encapsulate the `xxx` parameter in it's own object and pass that: `bar( {prop:this.xxx} );`
- Have `bar()` return the value and set it: `this.xxx = bar();`

Comment: Looks nice but still doesn't achieve what I'm looking for. The problem is that `bar()` is asynchronous so it can't return anything. So I think @arpit-agarwal 's solution is the only way to go.

Comment: The answer was more to explain *why it's not working. There's really only 3 ways to get around it. Going by the code you posted above, `bar()` is synchronous, so the return should work unless I'm missing something. Just give the answer to whoever posted first :D